# Extract both text and image using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, html-parsing

I'm extracting content from a web page. In web page the information like phone number and email id are stored in images. I want to extract the image and also the text inside that table. In the output string I want the output to be in same way as displayed in web page with image and text.

Below is the web page content.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>text</td>
   <td><img src="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>text</td>
   <td><img src="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>text</td>
   <td><img src="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can I get both text and image extracted like this:

> text img
>
> text img
>
> text img

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
HtmlNode imgNode = doc.DocumentElement.selectSingleNode("/table/tr/td/img");

//Just get Images only
foreach (HtmlNode img in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img"))
{
  string imgSrc = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
}

//get td's and ignore img in it
foreach (HtmlNode td in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//td"))
{
  HtmlNode img = td.ChildNodes["img"];
  if(img == null)
  {
    string tdText = td.InnerText;
  }
}

//Get Images that have style attribute
foreach (HtmlNode img in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//img[@style]"))
{
  string style = img.Attributes["style"].Value.ToLower();
  style = style.Replace("background:url('", "");
  style = style.Replace("')", "");
 //now you have the image url from the background

}
```

Comment: Thank you, HatSoft. DocumentElement is supporting in my code. I tried using DocumentNode. I have one more question, how to extract background image of img tag and store in my system.

Comment: <img style="background:Url('..//contactdetails?data=4512354367432554')" src="some transparent image"/>

Comment: @user1516690 i can give you the xpath to extract the style attribute contain background: etc, but if you their is no image file extension in it

Comment: HatSoft, that is the problem i'm facing. How can i get the image in this url. Is this possible to get the image from url?. This what i'm getting when i extract the html content from web page.

Comment: @user1516690 I can get the url out for you, this url returns an image content, so you will have to do use the url something liek this way <img src="htp:....." to get content out of it

Comment: That will be very help full HatSoft.

Comment: Please see updated answer showing how extract url form style background

Comment: Hello HatSoft,
‰PNG   IHDRxP˜Ù‚P...c’=|&ndash;ýMÂµùç³IEND&reg;B`‚
When i tried to extract the image using url, i got this output. I don't know which format this is in and how to get the contact number using this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (HtmlNode img in root.SelectNodes("//img"))
{
    string att = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
    anchorTags.Add(att);
}
```